# Loop to change outliers of multiple variables to 95% in R

Tags: r, loops

I have some outliers in my dataset. The variables of interest are named as `j_q3_1, j_q3_2,...,j_q3_14` and also `j_q4_1, j_q4_2,...,j_q4_14`. I want to change entries greater than the 95 percentile to the 95 percentile. I was wondering if I could create a loop that changes question number (q3 to q4) and also the last number after underscore (1 to 14). Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Example data (only until _2 and q3 and q4 only):

```
    test <- data.frame(hhid = c(1:5), j_q3_1 =c(1000,1500,2000,5000,10000), j_q4_1=c(500,100,200,10000,200), j_q5_1 =c(200,300,400,203,100), j_q3_2 =c(300,10000,200,300,200), j_q4_2=c(100,200,320,120,302), j_q5_2=c(10000,120,1222,300,2333))
```

This code works for me for every variable:

```
    quantiles <- quantile(test$j_q3_1,c(0.95))
    test$j_q3_1[test$j_q3_1 > quantiles[1]] <- quantiles[1]

    quantiles <- quantile(test$j_q4_1,c(0.95))
    test$j_q4_1[test$j_q4_1 > quantiles[1]] <- quantiles[1]

    quantiles <- quantile(test$j_q3_2,c(0.95))
    test$j_q3_2[test$j_q3_2 > quantiles[1]] <- quantiles[1]

    quantiles <- quantile(test$j_q4_2,c(0.95))
    test$j_q4_2[test$j_q3_2 > quantiles[1]] <- quantiles[1]
```

---

Now I tried to use the code to my whole dataset and changed the condition to the 99% confidence interval. It's not working as it should be since the outlier of 25000 remains the same when the 99% of the variable is 9260. It changed the mean from 1606 to 1813 though and decreased the NA's from 2825 to 2801 observations.

```
  for (i in 3:6){
    for (j in 1:14){
    cname <- paste0("j_q", i, "_", j)
    quantiles <- quantile(test[, cname], c(0.99), na.rm = TRUE)
    test[test[!is.na(test[, cname]), cname] > quantiles[1], cname] <- quantiles[1]
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide you same dataset and expected output so we can work on the same

Comment: Thanks. I added a sample dataset I am using to figure the loop out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
cname <- paste0("j_q", i, "_", j)
quantiles <- quantile(test[, cname], c(0.99))
test[test[, cname] > quantiles[1], cname] <- quantiles[1]
```

If you have NA values:

```
cname <- paste0("j_q", i, "_", j)
quantiles <- quantile(test[, cname], c(0.99), na.rm = TRUE)
test[!is.na(test[,cname]) & test[, cname] > quantiles[1], cname] <- quantiles[1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This code is exactly what I was looking for! There are some NA in my dataset though, how would I build it in the code? I tried    quantiles <- quantile(test[, cname], c(0.95), na.rm=TRUE) but it wouldn't work and gives me this error: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, test[, cname] > quantiles[1], cname,  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

Comment: This come from the na values in test[, cname]. Do you want to na to  stay na in your final data.frame?

Comment: Yes, I do want it to stay NA in the dataframe.

Comment: Yes, it worked with my sample dataset. I added an edit to my question above since it's not working as it should be when I use it to the whole dataset. Maybe I'm using the for loops wrongly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes my bad, my NA solution is broken i am editing the post again

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. That final edit made it work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good candidate for functional programming:

```
quantOut <- function(vec) {
  quantiles <- quantile(vec,c(0.95))
  vec[vec > quantiles[1]] <- quantiles[1]
  return(vec)
}
```

Now `quantOut` wraps the process you completed for one particular column. It can be used in whatever context necessary.

```
test %>% mutate_at(vars(j_q3_1:j_q4_14), quantOut)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fn_FindUpperLimit = function(x) quantile(x,0.95)
fn_ReplaceUpperExtreme = function(x) ifelse(x>quantile(x,0.95),quantile(x,0.95),x) 

mtcars %>% 
select(disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec) %>% 
mutate_each(funs(fn_FindUpperLimit),everything()) %>%
distinct()
#  disp     hp   drat      wt    qsec
#1  449 253.55 4.3145 5.29275 20.1045

mtcars %>% 
select(disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec) %>% 
mutate_each(funs(fn_ReplaceUpperExtreme),everything())


#    disp     hp   drat      wt    qsec
#1  160.0 110.00 3.9000 2.62000 16.4600
#2  160.0 110.00 3.9000 2.87500 17.0200
#3  108.0  93.00 3.8500 2.32000 18.6100
#4  258.0 110.00 3.0800 3.21500 19.4400
#5  360.0 175.00 3.1500 3.44000 17.0200
#6  225.0 105.00 2.7600 3.46000 20.1045
#7  360.0 245.00 3.2100 3.57000 15.8400
#8  146.7  62.00 3.6900 3.19000 20.0000
#9  140.8  95.00 3.9200 3.15000 20.1045
#10 167.6 123.00 3.9200 3.44000 18.3000
#11 167.6 123.00 3.9200 3.44000 18.9000
#12 275.8 180.00 3.0700 4.07000 17.4000
#13 275.8 180.00 3.0700 3.73000 17.6000
#14 275.8 180.00 3.0700 3.78000 18.0000
#15 449.0 205.00 2.9300 5.25000 17.9800
#16 449.0 215.00 3.0000 5.29275 17.8200
#17 440.0 230.00 3.2300 5.29275 17.4200
#18  78.7  66.00 4.0800 2.20000 19.4700
#19  75.7  52.00 4.3145 1.61500 18.5200
#20  71.1  65.00 4.2200 1.83500 19.9000
#21 120.1  97.00 3.7000 2.46500 20.0100
#22 318.0 150.00 2.7600 3.52000 16.8700
#23 304.0 150.00 3.1500 3.43500 17.3000
#24 350.0 245.00 3.7300 3.84000 15.4100
#25 400.0 175.00 3.0800 3.84500 17.0500
#26  79.0  66.00 4.0800 1.93500 18.9000
#27 120.3  91.00 4.3145 2.14000 16.7000
#28  95.1 113.00 3.7700 1.51300 16.9000
#29 351.0 253.55 4.2200 3.17000 14.5000
#30 145.0 175.00 3.6200 2.77000 15.5000
#31 301.0 253.55 3.5400 3.57000 14.6000
#32 121.0 109.00 4.1100 2.78000 18.6000
```

Answer (score 0):

simple with base R

```
quantile <- quantile(test$j_q3_1,0.95)
test[test>=10000] <- quantile

hhid j_q3_1 j_q4_1 j_q5_1 j_q3_2 j_q4_2 j_q5_2
1    1   1000    500    200    300    100   9000
2    2   1500    100    300   9000    200    120
3    3   2000    200    400    200    320   1222
4    4   5000   9000    203    300    120    300
5    5   9000    200    100    200    302   2333
```